# Creating/modifying a resource by sending a POST request to another (related) resource

Tags: rest, api-design

I am designing a RESTful API for tests and test runs metadata. I have two resources: `Test` and `TestRun`. Under the hood they have a one-to-one relationship in the database.

First I create a `Test` resource by sending a `POST` to `api/v1/test`.

Then I have to start this test. I do this by sending a `POST` to `api/v1/test/{id}/run`, which creates a `TestRun` resource that relates to that `Test` resource.

Then I can also stop the test by sending a `POST` to `api/v1/test/{id}/finish`, which modifies the corresponding `TestRun` resource (sets some fields, like `finish_time`, `result` etc.).

The user of the API will never have `GET` access to `TestRun` resources and will only access them through their related `Test` resources.

While it looks like this design is quite straightforward for the API user, I doubt this is also as straightforward for a developer. Is this design I came up with good enough? Does it violate any REST principles or best practices? I would appreciate any input on this.

An extended design description of the whole API: https://gist.github.com/Ch00k/27724e29ec1bf044ebbfdabef9e842d5

Comment: 'I doubt this is also as straightforward for a developer'. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Lutz Horn That's was a wrong question apparently :) I was just wondering if it's a good idea to it the way I did it, and if it's not against the REST best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Your API will not allow access to the testrun, so a testrun seems not to be a REST Resource. In fact your URLs are a mix of REST, as far as the test is concerned, and RPC, especially the `/run` and `/finish` paths.

RPC is not REST, so I would rework this a little bit:

- Use only *one* type of resource, the test, at `api/v1/test/{id}`.
- A test has state that can be retrievd using a `GET` request to `api/v1/test/{id}`:

  - `status`: `stopped`, `started`, `finished`, ...
  - `finish_time`
  - `result`
  - ...
- The state of a test is changed using a `PATCH` request to `api/v1/test/{id}` with a JSON body containing the new state: `{"status": "started"}` to start the test, etc. This replaces the RPC calls.

Comment: Would you also keep the existing database design? I.e. I will still have a Test table and a TestRun table, and when I issuing a PATCH request to api/v1/test/{id} will change the record in TestRun table.
Note that in my design the test itself does not have a state, but it's state is defined by the start_time and end_time of its TestRun.

Comment: I will actually add a status field, because it makes querying much easier.

Comment: REST has nothing to do with you persist the resources. A resource can be stored in more than one table.